# Android: Text View size and different font size

Tags: android, font-size, android-fonts, text-size

I have read a lot and still have not found the solution. I have an application that displays textviews, what I want to do is when I change the font sizes from the phone settings (large, small, medium) the textview size on the screen remains unchanged.

But after I tried following the sizes hpdi, xhdpi, xxhdpi... and set the textview size to "sp" then with different font sizes the textview size still gets bigger if I choose large font size.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried `dp`? However I can't imagine a situation where you wouldn't want the size to change.

Comment: @HenryTwist same result :<

Comment: That seems like it shouldn't be the case, can you include a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Actually sizes in hpdi, xhdpi, xxhdpi... folders are sizes for different phone screens and put different sizes in them is not related to have fixed font size(even phone size setting set to large).
You have to set size with `dp`, not `sp` to phone setting can not effect on text size.